# URL shortener for Opera 10.5

Tags: opera-10

I've recently used the Opera browser because it's now faster than Google Chrome.
But the problem is I can't make short URLs as fast as possible, because the URL shortener for Opera is a widget that runs outside Opera. Do you have a better idea on how to shorten URLs in Opera the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quick "tuto" regarding that, here is the link:

http://operawatch.com/news/2010/01/how-to-shorten-urls-directly-in-opera.html

> Method 1: Shorten URLs via the Opera address bar using custom search
>   It’s easy to create a custom search in Opera. But here I prove you can use it for more than searching! Create a custom search that posts to http://is.gd/create.php using URL=%s as your query string.
>
> Click OK, and you can now create a shortened URL directly from the Opera address bar by typing u  and hitting Enter, assuming you used “u” as the shortcut key.
>   Here is my original blog post with more detailed instructions:
>   http://my.opera.com/BAMAToNE/blog/2009/10/04/how-to-shorten-urls-from-the-opera-address-bar
>   Method 2: Shorten URLs via custom Opera button
>
> After my blog post became famous (thanks, Espen!), Opera Community member mistressEVIL furthered my idea and showed us a way to shorten URLs using a custom button. I think it’s a great idea because not everyone is comfortable customizing Opera the way I have shown. But using a custom button is easy because it just takes a click.
>
> Here is mistressEVIL’s blog post with more detailed instructions on how to create custom buttons:
>   http://my.opera.com/missevilat/blog/2010/01/15/shorten-url-with-a-button